# Getting "Internal Server Error" when using api deployed on vercel

Tags: node.js, express, multer, vercel

I have deployed the express app on vercel, other api are working fine but uploading image one is giving the error "Internal Server Error"

**upload api in index.js**

```
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});
```

**multer configuration**

```
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, req.body.name);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: multerStorage });
```

I am trying in postman by entering the form data which includes name and file but if I try with only uploading file in binary, it is getting successful.

Path is fine, api is working smoothly in local but dont know why it is not working after deploying.

**Github repo** - https://github.com/JavaKaran/techducant-backend

*Edit - 1*

**Error (getting in postman)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

*Edit - 2*

**vercel error for upload api**

[POST] /api/upload
2022-12-14T15:52:55.912Z    0988f1fa-ba5c-49b8-ae08-889cc67e7889    ERROR   Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'images/virtual.jpg'

Comment: Please include the full error traceback. The actual error on the server side, not the 500 the client sees

Comment: added the error getting in postman @mousetail

Comment: If you get a 500 error that means the error is on the server. Open the logs on vercel and copy the error message.

Comment: added the vercel error

Comment: Error seems clear enough, the file system is read only. You can't save anything there.

Comment: yeah, understood. my bad that I didn't went through the vercel logs. First time deployed a node application on vercel.

Thanks @mousetail